# What is benefit of project level connection manager other than common use across packages?

Tags: ssis

I have couple of connection managers inside package.

I am wondering whether I need to make them project level connection managers.

The only plus point is that the connection managers can then be shared with multiple packages.

What is benefit of project level connection manager other than common use across packages?

Answer (score 1):

A Project level connection manager is going to share the benefits of [Project level parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66497856/what-is-the-purpose-of-parameterizing-connection-manager-in-ssis)

There is a single view of a database connection which means only one entity needs to be updated when a service account password changes. Or a server name changes or a database is moved. I worked in an environment where as you moved up the environment tier, both your server and database name changed.

- SrvDev1 -> WebTeamDevDB
- SrvTest1 -> SLSTESTDB
- SrvLoad1 -> SLSLOADDB
- SrvStage1 -> SLSSTAGEDB
- SrvProd1 -> SLSPRODDB

Having all of the packages use a consistent, shared definition of connection managers greatly simplifies the development, maintenance and operation of your ETL.

n.b.
While any connection manager can be promoted/defined as a Project level connection manager, I have not seen a successful case for making file level connection managers a project scoped artifact.

### From the comments

> What's the issue with file level connection managers a project scoped artifact
> They work fine as package or project level connection managers. I've never had cause to use the same flat file connection manager across multiple packages.

If I have a sales file to import, only the SalesImporter SSIS package is going to need to know about it. Sales and Customer data likely reside in the same database so a shared, project level database connection manager makes sense. But only one package is likely to use the different Flat File Connection Managers. I *think* you have to pay the validation time for all the connection managers in a package so if there are 50 files to validate and only 1 is needed, why are we wasting time complicating our packages? As a maintainer, that would be my first question followed by - are these used somewhere I'm not seeing as I go digging through event handlers and anywhere else usage might have been ferreted away.

In summary, don't burden your packages with shared artifacts that shouldn't be shared.

Comment: What's the issue with file level connection managers a project scoped artifact.

Comment: Added a note about why I don't believe in file level connection managers